# an addition needed in highslide js

Tags: php, javascript, image, slider

Iam using highslide js for my image blow up section and its working fine. But now i need that once an image is clicked and is blown large then if a person clicks anywhere on the page except that image then the image should get back to its original self i.e. blow up should get removed.You can check it here http://highslide.com/
Even on original url the image blow up gets closes only when a user clicks on the image again or on close buttons if any.How can i close my image blow up when a user clicks somewhere else on the page and not on image?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution.Its just that i had to use the code which is being used at cross button .